# SQL Math evaluate Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

This evaluation in sql doesn't seems to work properly for some reason but i can't figure out why.

Lets take this example first.

```
DECLARE @countRatio decimal(6,3)     
SET @countRatio = (((4)/(2))*(6))/100.0
_______________________________________
0,120
```

This evaluation works like a charm. I also get the same answer with my calculator.

But this example give me an unexpected answer.

```
DECLARE @countRatio decimal(6,3)     
SET @countRatio = (((2)/(4))*(6))/100.0
_______________________________________
0,000
```

When i calculate this on my calculator the answer is 0,03
which acording to me is correct. But the sql keeps giving me 0,000 as the answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `((2)/(4))` is rounded down to an `INT` since 2 and 4 are both `INTs`. If you instead use 2.0 or 4.0 you get the right result:

```
DECLARE @countRatio decimal(6,3)     
SET @countRatio = (((2.0)/(4))*(6))/100.0
SELECT @countRatio 
==========================
0.030
```

In any arithmetic expression, SQL Server casts to the type of the operator that has the greater precision. So `2.0/4` casts the result to the type of `2.0`, which is `float`.

Answer (score 2):

`2` and `4` are integers, so SQL uses an integer division, that gives `0`. This will work:

```
DECLARE @countRatio decimal(6,3)      
SET @countRatio = (((2.0)/(4.0))*(6))/100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @countRatio decimal(6,3)      

-- Using integers 2 / 4 = 0:
set @countRatio = ( ( 2 / 4 ) * 6 ) / 100.0
select @countRatio

-- Using decimal values 2 / 4 = 0.5:
set @countRatio = ( ( 2. / 4. ) * 6. ) / 100.0
select @countRatio

-- Explicitly converting a value to decimal will cause the other values to be promoted to decimal:
set @countRatio = ( ( Cast( 2 as Decimal ) / 4 ) * 6 ) / 100.0 -- Decimals.
select @countRatio

-- Or:
set @countRatio = ( ( Convert( Decimal, 2 ) / 4 ) * 6 ) / 100.0 -- Decimals.
select @countRatio

-- The promotion occurs when it is needed.  Hence this doesn't do what you want:
set @countRatio = ( ( 2 / 4 ) * Convert( Decimal, 6 ) ) / 100.0 -- Decimals.
select @countRatio
```